# Eclipse: How to backup and restore session (windows, views)?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-kepler

Occasionally, my fingers are faster then my brain and accidentally close views or windows of my development environment (which is Eclipse Kepler). I usually have two windows of Eclipse running side by side with individual views configured in both of them. Unfortunately, as soon as I (unintentionally) close a view/window, I have to set it up again. E.g. the build files in my Ant view get lost, I have to reopen files and so on...

Generally speaking, are there any plug-ins or options you can recommend that can help me backup and restore sessions? I'm aware of the "Save perspective" feature, but it barely meets my needs.

To be more precise:

- Is there any feature to make Eclipse request my confirmation, before a (top-level Eclipse) window is closed? - I rarely do uncontrolled clicks twice :-)
- Is there any plugin to save and restore my current views (incl. build files in Ant view)?
- Is there any plugin to save a set of open files I'm currently working on? Would be neat, if I could open several files on a single click and get working right away. I'm thinking of a session management, where I can switch between several sets of open files.
- Just in case none of the above is available and I messed up again, are there any files I can copy from one workspace to another to restore my Eclipse setup (windows/views)?

Any hints are welcome.